# When do you draw loose tiles in Chinese Mahjong?

Tags: mahjong

I have been playing with English rules with a dead wall or ruin, which you can only access through flower/season tiles or Kongs.

We end up deadlocked often, so I wanted to try the Chinese style where you have no flowers or seasons, can have more than one Chow and no dead wall, so you can access the whole wall directly for a larger chance of finishing.

From [this rule description](http://www.mastersgames.com/rules/mah-jong-rules.htm) I understand you still have two 3rd layer or loose tiles from where you break the wall, but how/when do you draw them, just when you encounter that wall column?

Answer (score 2):

From [Tom Sloper's rules](http://www.sloperama.com/mjfaq/mjfaq10.html), there are no loose tiles:

- After breaking the wall, each player takes 2 stacks (4 tiles) at a time until everyone has 12 tiles, then:
- East takes *one* tile from the *first* and *third* stacks, and the following three players take one tile each in order.

This leaves East with 14 tiles and they discard to start the game.

[Here's another set of rules](https://mahjongtime.com/chinese-official-mahjong-rules-3.html) that describes the same procedure but also has a different ending (East simply takes 2 tiles in a stack at the end).

Comment: Ah OK, so just drop special scoring like "Gathering the Plum Blossom from the Roof" etc. Cool.